# Wait for setup project to close in .NET

Tags: vb.net, installation

My end result is that I want to launch another setup project after the first setup project closes. The problem is that since setup.exe is just a wrapper for the MSI package, WaitForExit is quitting when the setup.exe is finished and not foo.msi.

```
Using Process As New System.Diagnostics.Process
      Process.StartInfo.FileName = "setup.exe"
      Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
      Process.WaitForExit()
End Using

'Launch next setup here
```

What are ways to accomplish this? The setup is a Visual Studio Setup  Project.

I believe I am going to need to try out some professional installer products to see if I can get the results that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our company decided to go with InstallAware Studio Edition.  It was able to run setups after the installation was completely finished and everything else that I could possibly need.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
msiexec
```

to run your msi file instead of *setup.exe* (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262.aspx)

Here is a detailed example: [Launching MSIExec.exe From C#](http://murrayon.net/2008/06/launching-msiexecexe-from-c.html)

Comment: wont using msiexec bypass the prereq checking done in the setup.exe?

Comment: yes it would. setup.exe essentially contains the pre requisites check, which might be needed prior to install your application.